# Can't inject html string with input tag

Tags: javascript, html, angular

This is my sample HTML string which i am getting through one API , and I want to bind it with angular.

```
<div class="col-md-6">
     <div class="form-group has-danger">
         <label for="input1">Shirnkrap <span class="text-danger">*</span></label> 
             <div class="col-md-12"> 
                <select class="form-control" formControlName="shirnkrap">
                    <option value=no>NO</option><option value=yes>YES</option>
                </select>                          
            </div>   
     </div>
</div>
```

I am passing HTML string like this.

```
this.projectService.getDynamicField().
    then(content=> {
        this.dynamicFields = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(content); 
        //this.dynamicFields = content; 
    });
```

As output on angular page it shows only shows lable and `<option>` tag's YES and NO. in `console.log` I saw this `WARNING: sanitizing HTML stripped some content (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss).`
after searching on net I found solution to use this `this.dynamicFields = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(content);` which solve my one problem that content was not displaying, but this lead me to another problem that  built in validation of Angular not working.

**So what I want to do is bing HTML sting and built in validation of Angular should also work.**

This is my `component.ts` file code.

```
projectForm: FormGroup;
constructor(private sanitizer:DomSanitizer,private router: Router,private fb: FormBuilder,private projectService: ProjectService,private fnService:FunctionsService, private  userService : UserService) {

    this.dropzoneConfig ={ url : environment.apiurl+'/project/driveupload' };

    this.projectForm = fb.group({
        'project_name':[null, Validators.required],
        'shirnkrap':[null, Validators.required],
        'cd_text':[null, Validators.required]

    });
}
```

**Output without sanitizing**

[image: Output without sanitizing]

**Output with sanitizing**

[image]

**`console.log` after sanitizing**

[image: Console log after sanitizing]

**my HTML**

```
<form class="form-material form-horizontal" [formGroup]="projectForm" >
      <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-12" [innerHTML]="dynamicFields" id='dynamicHtml'>

            </div>
      </div>
</form>
```

So can someone guide me how can I get this working?

Comment: I did with javascript. it may help you.  html: <div class="col-md-12"  id='dynamicHtml'></div> , componet code: document.getElementById('dynamicHtml').innerHTML = this.dynamicFields;

Comment: your single line code and what i did in my script will have same effect, this is not solution i am looking for.